# Image of $[0,\pi/2]\times [0,\infty)$ under complex sine map is the first quadrant of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am required to show that the set $\{x+iy: 0\leq x\leq \pi/2, 0\leq y < \infty\}$ maps bijectively to the first quadrant along with the boundary axes under the sine map.

I am able to show that the image set is contained in the codomain and the map is injective. I am unable to show it is surjective.

I have tried using the definition of sine given by $\sin(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$ and also from the relation
$\sin(x+iy)=\sin(x)\cosh(y)+i \cos(x)\sinh(y)$.

In both cases, if I take some $a+ib$ with $a,b\geq 0$ and try to get a preimage $x+iy$, I am landing up into lots of equations which seems difficult to solve.

Any idea or trick to show the surjectivity would be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you figure out how the boundaries of your region map?

Comment: They are mapping to the non negative parts of the real and imaginary axes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write the sine function as a composition of the exponential function, Möbius transformations, and the square function:
$$
 \sin(z) = \frac{e^{2iz}-1}{2ie^{iz}} =
 \frac 12 \frac{(e^{iz}+i)^2+(e^{iz}-i)^2}{(e^{iz}+i)^2-(e^{iz}-i)^2}
= \frac 12 \frac{\left( \frac{e^{iz}+i}{e^{iz}-i}\right)^2+1}{\left( \frac{e^{iz}+i}{e^{iz}-i}\right)^2-1} \, .
$$
This allows to determine the image of $\{x+iy: 0\leq x\leq \pi/2, 0\leq y < \infty\}$ by successively applying the simpler functions.

You'll find that the image is not the upper half-plane but the first quadrant.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Show the imaginary part of the image is nonnegative under the given hypotheses.